# Android Hashmap return value from other class

Tags: android, function, textview, hashmap

i will like to pass the value from DatabaseHandler.java lets say "name" to mainActivity and show it on textview.

DatabaseHandler.java

```
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
    HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user
    return user;
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
TextView lblid;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

lblid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showid);
HashMap<string, string=""> details = getUserDetails();
        String nametext = details.getString("name");
        lblid.setText(nametext);
}
```

I am having trouble writing correct code to make it works, i keep getting "Syntax error on token". Please help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: This wont compile: HashMap<string, string="">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this line cause problem

```
HashMap<string, string=""> details = getUserDetails();
```

replace it with

```
HashMap<string, string> details = getUserDetails();
```

Usage exaple

Main.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
...
private DatabaseHandler dbh;
...
public void onCreate(Bundle) {
dbh = new DatabaseHandler(...);
...
}
...
HashMap<String, String> details = dbh.getUserDetails();
...
String nametext = details.get("name");
```

Comment: Thanks, but now i encounter **The method getUserDetails() is undefined for the type MainActivity** & **The method getString(String) is undefined for the type HashMap<R.string,R.string>** what is the problem??

Comment: its because getUserDetails() is method of DatabaseHandler not MainActivity. You need to have instance of DBH in you MainActivitiy. Also HashMap<> dont have method getString(Object) but get(Object). Check updated example

Comment: Thanks for helping out Bartex and also the explanation.